# How to perform keyword query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Here I have a BOOK collection:

```
 Book Id：001
 Book Name：C# step by step
 Book Description：Programming book on C#

 Book Id：002
 Book Name：Head First Java
 Book Description：Programming Book on Java

 Book Id：003
 Book Name：Steve Jobs
 Book Description：biography of Jobs
```

My question is how to search all books with the word "Programming" in Book Description?

I am newbie to NoSQL, currently I can only use find() to perform precise search rather than a keyword search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation has a chapter about [Full Text Search in Mongo](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Full+Text+Search+in+Mongo) which recommends to split each string into an array of individual words, so that you can index it for faster lookup.

```
{   Id：001,
    Name："C# step by step",
    Description："Programming book on C#",
    Description_tags: [
        "Programming",
        "book",
        "on",
        "C#"]
}

db.books.ensureIndex({Description_tags:1});

db.books.find(Description_tags:"Programming");
```

When speed is not an issue and you want to avoid changing your data structure, you can also use [regular expressions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/). But keep in mind that this scales badly: the lookup time will be linear to the number of entries in the collection.

```
db.collection.find( {description: { $regex: "Programming"} } );
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but can I make the query to support case-insensitive? Because I found MongoDB treats the keyword "Good" and "good" differently.

Comment: When you form the documents standardise the text to all lowercase

Comment: When you use the regular expression approach, you can use the "i" for "insensitive" option: `db.collection.find( {description: { $regex: "Programming", $options: "i" }`. When you use the tag approach, you should generate the tags in lower-case and also convert the user-input to your find query to lower-case.

Comment: If I have an array I want to search with like ["programming", "steve"] will this still work?

Comment: @NathanielDSouza Check out the [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/) operator which will return documents where *either* word is in the array. If you want those where *both* are in the array, you need to use [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and). But also note that this is a very old answer. [Full text search in MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) made some considerable advances in the past years.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression in the query selector of a `find` to do that:

```js
db.books.find({description: /Programming/})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to find using keyword in mongoDB, among them i would like [Text-Search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/).

1. Create Index For `Book Name` and `Book Description`

   you need to create index for `Book Name` and `Book Description` with `Text` ex `db.books.createIndex( { BookName: "text", BookDescription: "text" } )`
2. Now query your docs simply by `db.books.find( { $text: { $search: "Programming" } } )`

It might help you to find all relevant document, which contain programming keyword from `Book Name` and `Book Description`.